# QR code not generated for Azure AD B2C custom totp sample

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, totp

I am following this sample [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp) and have deployed it and integrated it with my test Azure AD B2C user sign in journey. However, when it loads the page (selfasserted-appfactor-registration.html), there is no QR code. I don't see anything in the documentation regarding this.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your 'Run Now' link? Are there any errors in the console? Do you see the <Script> elements if you inspect the page?

Comment: the run now link won't help because only after you log in, you are presented with the page. there are quite a few script tags when i look at the page source including the minimized jquery that's inserted there by ad b2c.

Comment: also there are no errors in the console

Comment: Look at the JS script tag in the HTML file as part of the sample - do you see this script tags on your page via the Run Now link? The sample works by getting a base64 encoded image and using JS to convert it into an image client side.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT, it's finally working. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Riz how it work can you explain?

Comment: I have what seems like a similar question     . The current samples have you upload the qrcode.mini.js file to azure blob. But it does not render when you run the B2C policy. It renders only when you hit the app endpoint via local host or using ngrok. I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77907426/azure-b2c-with-verifiable-credentials-qr-code-not-generated-in-selfasserted-ht

Comment: This is for verifiable credentials with B2C though.