# Azure B2C With Verifiable Credentials - QR Code Not Generated in SelfAsserted.html

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

Following the Verifiable Credentials B2C Sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials/blob/main/B2C/README.md

I have updated the selfasserted.html file with the path (in Azure Storage) of qrcode.min.js. But none of the following B2C policies render the QRCode when the user journey is run. This means a verifiable credential can neither be issued nor verified.

B2C_1A_SIGNINMFA_VC
B2C_1A_SIGNIN_VC
B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN_VC
B2C_1A_VC_SUSIQ
B2C_1A_VC_SUSI_ISSUEVC
However, there are no issues loading the QR code when hitting the app endpoint directly via localhost or using ngrok. Only seems to happen when going via Azure B2C.

UPDATE 1

After updating the sample to use the claim resolver everywhere VCStateId is used as an input claim as well as adding the metadata key I notice the following

1. The request url now has an id parameter, except that it is exactly "{Context:CorrelationId}" and not resolving to the actual correlation id. I see the following under headers in dev tools (sanitized)
   "Request URL:
   [https://xxxx-xxxx.ngrok-free.app/api/verifier/presentation-response-status?id={Context:CorrelationId}"](https://xxxx-xxxx.ngrok-free.app/api/verifier/presentation-response-status?id=%7BContext:CorrelationId%7D%22)
2. I see the script for the initial page you see when using ngrok, that warns you about proceeding only of you trust the site

UPDATE 2

I now consistently see an 'id' getting added to the request url. I was missing one more spot to add the metadata key IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling => true. But still, no qrcode.

UPDATE 3

I went a step further and made a bit of progress. I added an header in ngrok to skip the warning page and was able to get rid of the error: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON". Now here is what I see in console:

*Generating QR code encoded with openid://vc/?request_uri=https ://xxx.ngrok-free. app/api/verifier/presentation-request-proxy?id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx*

***QRCode is not defined***

Also in the B2C sign in page, instead of the QR code I see the screenshot

[image]

UPDATE 4

[image]

Comment: Can you add the "run now" url for testing?

Comment: Here it is. Please note that the sample app is exposed via ngrok and I may not have it powered on. But the part I need help with is just getting the qr.code to load.

https://morphitcg1.b2clogin.com/morphitCG1.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SIGNIN_VC&client_id=8328e52a-cef6-4b2c-9263-0ac55f6b5d8a&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Comment: I am not a frontend person and that is why I am struggling here. But I have tracked down the problem I believe. I threw a couple of console.logs in the JavaScript for the selfasserted.html and discovered that the requestURL is incomplete. Specifically it is missing the requestID which has a dependency on the VCStateId element.
However, document.getElementById("VCStateId").value would return null wherever it is used as there is no element with id that is VCStateId. I am stuck here for now. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hey @bolt-io found anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not, your ngrok tunnel wasn't up when I tried. It could be a CORS issue, is your B2C tenant on the allowed CORS policy when the app is running?

Comment: Oh no. Not a CORS issue since the html itself is retrieved successfully. The issue is related  to the request id not getting added, which depends on VCStateId as I described above.

Comment: I'll update in an answer due to the length and evidence I found so far.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far @bolt-io! I updated the question with improvements and notes i found because of the volume of info.

Comment: @bolt-io So, I am at the point where I now consistently get an 'id' in the request url. But I still cannot get the QRCode to load. Running the B2C_1A_SIGNIN_VC comes up with no QRcode to scan, no http request in ngrok, and nothing in the terminal of the sample app suggesting a request came in.

Comment: Do you get a response from the API with a URL?
I know there was a bug with the make QR function, so I added some padding to the url: `qrcode.makeCode(respPresReq.url.padEnd(220));` does your code pad the presentation request url?

Comment: when i inspect the page the request is "
https:// xxxxx.ngrok-url/api/verifier/presentation-response-status?id=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" and the response to that is the preview page of ngrok with a message like "You are about to visit xxxx.ngrok-free.app, served by x.xxx.xx.xxx..." But that page doesn't load in the browser.

Comment: What is strange is if I go directly to the /issuer.html page (not via B2C) and try to issue a credential. The QR code loads and when I scan it and try to login with my B2C account, it gets stuck on the same ngrok page. I am  not sure what the redirect uri on the app registration in B2C should for the OIDC auth. For now I have it as the ngrok (root) url.

Comment: Was finally able to get the error from attempting to sign in with a B2C account after scanning the qrcode (when hitting the sample app directly via ngrok not via B2C). It mentioned that "vcclient://openid" is not registered on the app registration in B2C. Added this uri but it made no difference.

Comment: Edit to last comment: this now works, there was just a delay it seems. But it has not helped my qrcode loading issue. But at least I know sample app is properly configured. I totally forgot I had "vcclient://openid" as the redirect uri in the rules definition.

Comment: I have always seen this error in the console when inspecting the page "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON". The ngrok preview page I mentioned above indeed is html and not json. Not sure if this means anything.

Comment: Has your ngrok tunnel URL changed? Make sure they are the same and that you can postman to the API using the tunnel (not localhost)

Comment: The tunnel is up. I can reach the app through it from the internet. The QR code is just not generating. I went a step further and made a bit of progress. I added an header in ngrok to skip the warning page and was able to get rid of the error: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON". Now here is what I see in console: 

Generating QR code encoded with openid://vc/?request_uri=https ://xxx.ngrok-free. app/api/verifier/presentation-request-proxy?id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

QRCode is not defined

Comment: Also in the B2C sign in page, instead of the QR code I see the screenshot in Update 3 in description.

Comment: Like to add again that I can reach the sample app directly if I go by the ngrok url. The QR code loads without issues there when I try to issue or verify a VC. The QR code does not load when going via a B2C policy.

Comment: RE update 3 seeing the two fields. This is because your HTML template has errors in it. Download the contents of the storage blob and fire it into vc code and it'll tell you where. There are a few that have a `;.` which is a syntax error. For example: `.catch((err) => console.log(err));.then(function(response) {`

Comment: Thanks @bolt-io. I took out those errors. Now I see the screenshot in Update 4. And get this error - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')". Suggesting that response.length > 0 (in callPresentationResponseStatus(id)) is the issue maybe because response is undefined or cannot have a length property.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like the sample has been updated on the sign-up/sign-in quick flow but not the others.

On the SignupOrSigninVCQ policy, the technical profile that is executed sets the `VCStateId` to the Correlation ID of the journey.

```xml
        <!-- TP that gets executed after QR code is scanned on signin page -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-VCSigninQuick">
          <DisplayName>Verifiable Credentials</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.vc</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <!-- if you change this one, you need to change the all ServiceUrl in this file -->
            <!-- CHANGE THE BELOW LINE -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCServiceUrl" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="https://df4a-158-174-131-118.ngrok.io/api/verifier" />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCServiceUrl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCCredentialType" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCCredentialType" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCSubject" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCIssuer" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCKey" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="DID" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-VC-GetAuthResult" />
            <!-- make sure the user exists in the directory -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Compare this to the SigninVC policies technical profile, you can see that the input claim `VCStateId` is never given a default value.

```xml
        <!-- Signing in with a VC when VC references a B2C account -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-VCSignin">
          <DisplayName>Verifiable Credentials</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.vc</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" />
            <!-- if you change this one, you need to change the all ServiceUrl in this file -->
            <!-- CHANGE THE BELOW LINE -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCServiceUrl" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="https://df4a-158-174-131-118.ngrok.io/api/verifier"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCServiceUrl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="vcCredentialType" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="vcSubject" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="vcIssuer" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="vcKey" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="DID" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-VC-GetAuthResult" />
            <!-- make sure the user exists in the directory -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

A few changes to make this work are:

Any input claims for `VCStateId` should be updated to have a default value:

```xml
<!-- before -->
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" />

<!-- after -->
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VCStateId" DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
```

You will also need to add the Claims Resolver metadata to each of the technical profiles you change:

```xml
<Metadata>
  ...
  <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
</Metadata>
```

The presentation request should now include the `id` in the query string.

---

*Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.*

Answer (score 0):

Closing this. The sample was just refreshed (less than 48 hours ago) with several changes. But for anyone who cares, I was finally able to resolve this issue by  modifying the chaining of the promises related to the fetch in function callPresentationResponse(id). After the catch block .then(response => response.text()) is trying to access the response variable. But at this point, it is not the response from fetch but the undefined value or error caught by the previous catch block. This leaves response undefined and by extension respMsg. Did the same for the same for the getQRCode function. Now, I am able to scan the QR code during issuance and verification. There were other issues after that but like I said the repo has been refreshed and there have been significant changes. But if not that, I'd be opening another question for it anyways. Thanks to @bolt-io for his contribution.